# Working on external grants during one's PhD

Tags: phd, research-process

**Scenario:** Person A is an incoming Phd Student at University X.

Person A is then offered an opportunity for a 3 year project part of another research group from University Y which does not mandate him to be a phd scholar in their group. This opportunity involves stipend. (Assume it to be a 3 year continuous internship with very high flexibility)

**Question:** Would it be wise to accept this offer without consulting anyone in the incoming university?

Comment: Can you, should you, switch to Y?

Comment: This is just a hypothetical situation. Would you suggest this?

Comment: Yes, I would suggest switching, all else being equal.

Comment: Personally, I don't think there's nearly enough information for us to help you decide. I can guess what the advantages of X and Y might be, but there's no way for us to rank these options without more details. Further, I can't tell if you are trying to choose between these options, or if you want to do both of these and are asking about the best strategy for getting X to agree to this. In the latter case, the answer will largely depend on the details of your agreement with X (in particular, whether X is funding you).

Answer (score 3):

No, you should not accept this offer without consulting university x. You are likely limited in the outside work that you can undertake.

This is assuming that you are receiving financial support from University X. If you are not, then they have little grounds to say no, although university regulations should always be consulted, particularly if you are on a student visa.

Comment: At least in the UK it is common that university regulations limit how many hours students (including PhD) can spend on outside employment. This is unrelated to any funding.

Comment: @Arno More precisely, if one has a full-time job (such as working for B), a PhD needs to be part-time. There are constellations where one works on a job which happens to be equivalent to what you need to do for a PhD, but this is not the default.